# Cannot open database "Test" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\$Test'

Tags: sql-server

After deploying a Linq to Sql Application in IIS ,the application throws this error.

**Cannot open database "Test" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\$Test'**.

It works perfectly fine in my development machine, following is my connection string

add key="Connection" value="Data Source=server-name;Initial Catalog=DbName;Integrated Security=SSPI"

The Account has enough permissions on Sql server.

Please help.

Comment: have a look to this article, may this help you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332

Comment: Is the identity on your application pool for your application configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved..my bad...

The connection string was stored in the settings file which i didn't notice and it was pointing to dev. and windows account didn't have permission.

Thanks...